# How to manage Google Analytics data based on hierarchical way

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am pretty new to Google Analytics, I am confused about how to capture data based on my requirement. attached here my requirement. I have different aggregated KPI to capture data. But this hierarchy seems to me pretty complex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show us what you have tired so far.

Comment: I am not familiar with GA, but is it worth adding your configuration to your post?